# TypeError: video_playlist is null JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a video playlist and I am new to JS, so I have run into a lot of problems.

I am trying to run this code:

```js
//Simple JS Playlist by Kristi Witts - https://github.com/kwitts/js-playlist/
//MIT License

//Ensure all links in the div "#player" act in the same way:
var video_playlist = document.getElementById("myVideo"); //Element ID should be the same as the ID used in the container div in the HTML.
var links = video_playlist.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].onclick = handler;
};
//Give functionality to the links:
function handler(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //Prevents default action of links going directly to the source file
  videotarget = this.getAttribute("href"); //looks at the filename in the link's href attribute
  filename = videotarget.substr(0, videotarget.lastIndexOf('.')) || videotarget; //Splits the filename and takes everything before the ".", giving us just name without the extension
  video = document.querySelector("#myVideo video"); //Finds div #player and video
  video.removeAttribute("poster"); //Removes the poster attribute in the video tag
  source = document.querySelectorAll("#myVideo video source"); //Finds source elements inside the video tag
  source[0].src = filename + ".mp4"; //defines the MP4 source
  video.load(); //Loads video when video is selected
  video.play(); //Plays video automatically
  return false;
};
```

```html
<div class="six columns">
  <div class="videoContainer">
    <video id="myVideo" controls preload="auto" poster="images/1-thm.png" width="600" height="350">
      <source src="videos/1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      <p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
    </video>
    <div class="caption">Screamer 2015 Intro</div>
    <div class="control">
      <div class="topControl">
        <div class="progress">
          <span class="bufferBar"></span>
          <span class="timeBar"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="time">
          <span class="current"></span><i>/</i> 
          <span class="duration"></span> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btmControl">
        <div class="btnPlay btn" title="Play/Pause video"></div>
        <div class="btnFS btn" title="Switch to full screen"></div>
        <div class="volume" title="Set volume">
          <span class="volumeBar"><i></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="sound sound2 btn" title="Mute/Unmute sound"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="loading"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="five columns" id="playlist-parent">
  <div id="playlist">
    <img src="#" class="thumbnails" id="2"><a href="videos/2.mp4">Screamer | Intro | Version (Step Style)</a>
    <img src="#" class="thumbnails" id="3"><a href="videos/3.mp4">Screamer | Speedart | Joined Naive! </a>
    <img src="#" class="thumbnails" id="4"><a href="videos/4.mp4">Screamer | Speedart | AE7 Banner</a>
    <img src="#" class="thumbnails" id="5"><a href="videos/5.mp4">Screamer | Speedart | Luck 7 Snipers Banner</a>
    <img src="#" class="thumbnails" id="6"><a href="videos/6.mp4">Screamer | Speedart | ESmthz Banner (Client Work)</a>
    <img src="#" class="thumbnails" id="7"><a href="videos/7.mp4">Screamer | Speedart | Solar #SolarDRC</a>
    <img src="#" class="thumbnails" id="8"><a href="videos/8.mp4">Screamer | Speedart | Dare Creations</a>
    <img src="#" class="thumbnails" id="9"><a href="videos/9.mp4">Screamer | Speedart | Line Banner | New Style?</a>
    <img src="#" class="thumbnails" id="10"><a href="videos/10.mp4">Screamer | Speedart | Version 2-in-1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I am getting `TypeError: video_playlist is null`
I would like to know why this is happening and what I can do to fix it, and prevent it in the future after I know how it happened.

For some reason (I think it may be this video_player is null) my playlist does not replace the video in the video player, but it opens and plays the video like it would normally do if you selected the file>open with>firefox.

Comment: Where is your script in relation to your html?  If before, the element won't exist when trying to get it through `getElementById`, unless in some sort of onload callback.

Comment: My script is in a separate file.

Comment: Nevertheless, if the `<script>` tag that's including it is, say, in the `<head>`, it will be running before the DOM is available, and elements won't get found.

Comment: Oh. Yea, that is where I put it. Where should I be putting it? I put it at the end but before </body> and it WORKED!!!! You should put this as an anwser and It is correct!

Comment: Take a look at the question I linked to - it has far more details than I can go into in a comment here.

Comment: There's no need to write a new answer - you should have a button available saying that the linked duplicate helped you?

Comment: Yes! I see it after refreshing the page! And please don't downvote me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript doesn't reference the dom. The issues are that you have a video element with a source element beneath it, but you're using

```
video = document.querySelector("#myVideo video")
```

You later call video.load(), but this is on the source element, not the video element. I have reloaded video to call load on it

```
video = document.getElementById("myVideo")
```

Here it is, fixed:

```
//Simple JS Playlist by Kristi Witts - https://github.com/kwitts/js-playlist/
//MIT License

//Ensure all links in the div "#player" act in the same way:
var video_playlist = document.getElementById("playlist"); //Element ID should be the same as the ID used in the container div in the HTML.
var links = video_playlist.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].onclick = handler;
};
//Give functionality to the links:
function handler(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //Prevents default action of links going directly to the source file
  videotarget = this.getAttribute("href"); //looks at the filename in the link's href attribute
  filename = videotarget.substr(0, videotarget.lastIndexOf('.')) || videotarget; //Splits the filename and takes everything before the ".", giving us just name without the extension
  video = document.querySelector("#myVideo source"); //Finds div #player and video
  video.removeAttribute("poster"); //Removes the poster attribute in the video tag
  source = document.querySelectorAll("#myVideo source"); //Finds source elements inside the video tag
  source[0].src = filename + ".mp4"; //defines the MP4 source
  video = document.getElementById("myVideo")
  video.load(); //Loads video when video is selected
  video.play(); //Plays video automatically
  return false;
};
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d2tgyfzb/

Comment: It still gives me the error. Can you tell me why this code is not replacing the video in the video player, but instead opening the video in a new document, the URL goes like ...server/portfolio/portfolio.html to ...server/portfolio/videos/2.mp4

Comment: You and the @JamesThrope solved my issue, thanks!